# Win 10 MySQL startup config file (my.ini) not loading the data directory

Tags: mysql, windows

So I have been using wamp just for the MySQL side of things but I decided to upgrade since wamp was using MySQL v5. So I have installed MySQL version 8.

I'm using a database about 60GB stored on my external SSD my problem is when I installed the new MySQL v8 I had to update the my.ini to state the external DB but for some reason, it just will not read from the my.ini file.

Below is an image with the my.ini, MySQL Workbench showing it is using that my.ini file for config and also showing that it not using the data path specified in my.ini.

[image]

Even when I start both the daemon and the client with explicit arguments saying I was to use that config, it still ignores.

One idea came to mind that since I have got a bunch of MYD/FRM/MYI files and this is a new DB would I have to import them somehow?

[image]
Is that why it does not want to read the tables?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see why you think you need to import the files in the data folder. In fact all you need to do is to copay the old folder and past it inside the new mysql server folder.

Inside the new mysql folder, open the prompt and execute the command:

```
mysql_upgrade -u 'user_name' -p
```

Enter the password and it will take care of upgrading the old data.